# is it possible to speed up writes inside a docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a very large file in my docker container (it's a virtualbox image) which --- unfortunately -- must be modified as part of running it. Docker's copy-on-write policy works against me here and unfortunately any mutation/copying of the file takes about 10 minutes, compared to about 10 seconds to copy the same file on the host.

Can anything be done to speed up the creation/copy of very large files within a docker container? Note that this is an entirely transient file that I do not need to persist after the container is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the folder the file is in as a volume. If you do this, the copy-on-write-policy is not applied. Note that you don't have to mount this volume to the host system, it is sufficient to declare it as a volume.

For more information: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Comment: I'm not trying to avoid copy on write (I don't want to modify the underlying file), I'm trying to speed up the ability to copy files / create new ones. Is there some magic involved when creating new files in a non-volume directory?

Comment: Files in this volume are not part of the layered file-system docker uses to build the images. The performance of read/write to a volume should be almost at the speed of the linux-host without isolation.

Comment: maybe I could mount the /tmp and do all my work in there. Is there no area in a container that is already considered transient? (other than the RAM disk, which is precious)

Comment: This is a good idea. I don't think there is already a transient part.